# XSD design of an xml element of dynamic sub-structure

Tags: xml, xsd, structure

I guess the word dynamic is misleading. The element of my interest could have three possible substructures. An example could be:

```
<body> 
    <date></date>
    <addr></addr>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
    <loc></loc>
    <time> </time>
    <city> </city>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
    //a whole lot of different sub elements
</body>
```

I am stuck in design the XSD that can be used to validate the three structures above (the three structures are known and fixed). I am not sure if I have put this question properly. Please shed any light on the solution, or even on the feasibility of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work I think:

```
<xs:group name="group_one">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="date"/>
     <xs:element name="addr"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="group_two">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="loc"/>
    <xs:element name="time"/>
    <xs:element name="city"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="body">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:group ref="group_one" />
    <xs:group ref="group_two"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

You can of course add more groups, and have more choices.

Comment: For completeness... there is a potential caveat, since the third group is not clearly defined...due to the XSD's Unique Particle Attribution constraint. In other words, if the third group would start with any of the `date` or `loc`, then the above solution would require amendments.

Comment: @PetruGardea   Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I am targeting.

Comment: @Petter Exactly what I need. Just another question here, didn't find much info on the web. In my case, the groups will need to use xs:all for the subelements because they are in arbitrary order, and the body element is not the root element in my entire xml document. After I made all the adjustments,the vs2012 gave me "The group ref to 'all' is not the root particle, or it is being used as an extension" warning. As I understand, it is not allowed is xml specs 1.0. But is there a workaround, provided that no change is made to the xml doc I am vidating?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your <body> to contain arbitrary xml fragment using CDATA.

```
    <xs:element name="body" type="xs:CDATA"/>
```

More info, please refer http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-xmlschema-2-20001024/#CDATA